# ProjectLocker and TortoiseGit

Tags: git, tortoisegit, projectlocker

I am trying to setup ProjectLocker with TortoiseGit. 
I have followed all the steps needed but keep getting the following error when I try to push to the remote server

> Pushing to git-davidmz@pl3.projectlocker.com:gemscope.git
>
> ERROR:gitosis.serve.main:Arguments to command look dangerous
>
> fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

I can't find what is wrong and hope someone can help me with the settings that are wrong.

P.S

I used this website
http://www.webupdate24.com/git-in-windows-with-tortoisegit-client-projectlocker-free-git-hosting.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend connecting from the bash command line to troubleshoot. TortoiseGit relies on msysgit to be installed underneath.

Further, use gitolite instead of gitosis as gitosis is no longer actively developed.

Your issue is probably with what key you are presenting and how you set up your admin repository.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you give me a fast command line arguments to test my connection?

Comment: you should be able to do a `git clone <url>` to see if you connect.